# How to create myown map with gps loction track

Tags: php, android, jquery, mysql, gps

I would like to create a web application that people can use for to locate them self with GPS tracking.

criteria:

1. I have to use my own map for a particular location
2. It is a web application that will work with all new generation browsers mainly for mobiles
   and tablets
3. whenever I am moving one place to other the pointer should change the location according 
   the place in map.

is it possible to create in a web application?

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 you can do it, see this example [Get user location within Google Map](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_map)

To get updates for user location, you should implement **watchPosition** function in your JavaScript code too.

At first time, with `getCurrentPosition` function, you will get an aproximate user location, if you need more accuracy, you should implemente **watchPosition**

> By calling this method as soon as your app starts, the GPS hardware will activate immediately and keep running, and it’ll fire callbacks whenever the device’s location has changed.

Read more here [HTML5 Geolocation: Improving GPS Accuracy](http://www.wastedintelligence.com/blog/2012/03/01/html5-geolocation-improving-gps-accuracy/)

Comment: thanks for your valuable Help.

Comment: Actually I have a place map about 10 KM I want to get the location in which place I am standing. is that possible I have an Android phone n Tab